# Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9 - is there a way to run a background operation?

Tags: swift, uiscenedelegate

I have noticed that when my app is running in the foreground, and then i explicitly terminate the my app by swiping up, then sceneDidDisconnect() is called.  This is great, the enables me to do some tidying up.

However, when the app is no longer in the foreground and I explicitly terminate the app, this function is not called, and i am unable to run any background operation to release resources etc.  Is there a way to run a background operation in this event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can't intercept termination with signal 9 / SIGKILL.